# Crosshatched fill for polygons in overlapping categories in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, fields-attributes, fill

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I have a polygon layer whose color needs to represent certain categories. There are a couple of polygons that belong to two categories at once (in the attribute table, the relevant cells literally contain a value of "[category 1], [category 2]").

Is there a way of showing this on the map with a crosshatched fill for those polygons, i.e., alternating diagonal lines of either color filling the polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a single symbology that included both colours on alternating lines, but I would not do it that way.

For situations like this, if there are 4 or less categories, I would symbolise each category with a cross hatch of a **different colour** *AND* **different direction** (vertical, horizontal, diagonal, diagonal the other way).  This way will work even if an area includes all 4 categories.

(For more than 4 categories, you'd have to come up with some other combination of symbologies that could not possibly obscure each other.  Eg, You could do 8 categories, by offsetting another 4 by half the distance between the lines.)

Then, as @michael_stimson commented, use a separate layer for each category, with definition queries for each layer to include only the features that match that category (including those that also match oither categories).

As @michael_stimson commented, your definition queries could look like:

- `field LIKE '%[category 1]%'`
- `field LIKE '%[category 2]%'`

(Note that as a general rule of thumb, its usually better to avoid a data model that could have multiple values in a field.  Other options could include using a many-to-many relationship, or having two copies of a feature that is in two categories.  This way, **you'd only need a single layer** using the "Categories" -> "Unique values" option in the Symbology tab, which would be the preferred and easier way to symbolise categories.  This would avoid the need for a separate layer for each category.)